# Can you get the input arguments from a method outside of main without passing the arguments?

Tags: java, args

I was trying a coding challenge and I recieved a 0 on it because I couldn't figure out how to get the input arguments. Is there another way of getting the inputs without passing it through a method in main?

I've looked all over the internet trying to find a different way to get the args but I can't figure it out. I also messaged the people hosting it and they said that it was completely fine.

```java
//both classes in same file

public class MyAnswer {
    public void solveIt() {
        // Is there a way to get the args without passing them to this 
        //method?
    }

}

//This entire class was uneditable.
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyAnswer.solveIt();
    }
}
```

If this isn't possible is there ever another way to get the args without it getting passed to you in a method or getting it set to an instance variable? Such as if they were in the same class?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: `solveIt()` should be accessed in a static way

Comment: @alea `solveIt()` *is* accessed in a static way. It'll fail to compile since the method isn't actually `static`, but the method call is "in a static way", given that it is qualified by the class name.

Comment: if you don't want to pass it through slveIt(), you can pass the through the constructor of MyAnswer, or you can create a method in MyAnswer to pass the parameter and store them as propeties of MyAnswer

Comment: @Robin And how will he call that constructor from `Solution`?  He cannot modify that class.

Comment: @Nexevis, I don't notice that the class was uneditable, if that's the case, there is no way to pass it the args in the main to MyAnswer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the `Scanner` class in your function to consume the inputs given to the program.

Answer (score 0):

I did some snooping and I think you can do Scanner temp = new Scanner(System.in); and it will work in a different class.